# Choosing the next number from another table in a query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have a variable `$a` which is an integer.

Then I have a table with a row called `MaxValue`.

I want to do an eloquent query to find the first MaxValue ocurrence bigger than `$a`.

I can do it easily with SQL but I would rather do it correctly with Eloquent.

Something like this:

```
Item::where('MaxValue', '>=',$a)->first();
```

Comment: apply order by maxvalue desc and your above query both should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Item::where('MaxValue', '>=', $a)->order_by('MaxValue', 'desc')->first();
```